# Having trouble parsing this triple negative sentence

Tags: grammar, negation, parsing

In my JLPT practise book, there is this sentence, which is designed to test if one can track all the negations:

> その仕事{しごと}ほどおもしろくない仕事{しごと}はないのではないかと、私{わたし}は思{おも}った。

Up to `の`, I think it's saying, "there is no job as uninteresting as that job." But then we hit `のではない`, and I get a bit lost. I feel like it's saying "there is no job where there is no job as boring as that job," which doesn't really make sense.

How do I parse this sentence so that I can understand whether the speaker thinks `その仕事{しごと}` is interesting or uninteresting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about parsing it as this:

> 「『その仕事ほどおもしろくない仕事はない』のではないか？」と、私は思った。

... reading [～～のではないか？](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B) as a rhetorical question.

---

You can say 「[～(の)ではないかと思う](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86)」(or more colloquially [～～(ん)じゃないかと思う](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86)) to mean "I suspect that~~" or "I think it probably is~~".

Comment: Nice. Adding in the extra quote brackets is helpful, but taking `のではないか` as set phrase was the key for me. Also, I really appreciate that you helped me parse the sentence without giving away the answer on what the speaker is definitely saying about `その仕事`, so that I could reach the answer on my own.

Answer (score 4):

He thinks that "that job" is very uninteresting.

I'm sorry I can't split this grammatically, but 「～のではないか」 corresponds to "I wonder whether **～～**", where **～～** is something (often bad) which can actually happen.

You can see many examples [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B).

```
その仕事ほどおもしろくない仕事はないのではないかと、私は思った。
"I'm afraid that there is no job as uninteresting as this," I thought.
```

Answer (score 4):

> その[仕事]{しごと}ほどおもしろくない[仕事]{しごと}

A job as boring as that one

> はない

Does not exist. There is not such a job.

> のではないかと、[私]{わたし}は[思]{おも}った。

のではない or んじゃない + か being a rhetorical question marker, a supposition, a "wondering if."

So basically you get something like "I wondered if there's a job as boring as that one."